# Why Render menu function of Autocomplete jQuery is not working with Grid view 2nd row?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am using Render menu function of Autocomplete jQuery  to show the tabular format in autocomplete list. I am geting the result in tabular format  for the first row of grid view but it's not working for 2nd row onwards..

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Port(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=txtPort]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    if (request.term.lastIndexOf("/") == (request.term.length - 1)) {
                        var term = request.term.slice(0, -1);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetAutocomplete") %>',
                            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            mustMatch: true,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.split('^')[0],
                                        val: item.split('^')[1]
                                    }
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {

                            },
                            failure: function (response) {

                            }
                        });
                    };
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id*=hdnPort]").val(i.item.val);
                    if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                        $("[id*=hdnPort]").val(-1);
                        document.getElementById("[id*=txtPort]").value = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                minLength: 0
            })//.bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });
            .data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    if (index == 0) ul.prepend("<table ><tr><td height='5px'>" + "" + "</td></tr></table>");
                    if (index == 0) ul.prepend("<table class='header-auto'><tr><td width='205px'>" + "PORT CODE" + "</td>" + "<td width='145px'>" + "PORT NAME" + "</td></tr></table>");
                    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).
                   append("<a><table>" + "<tr ><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='140px'>" + item.val.split('~')[3] + "</td></tr>" + "</table></a>").appendTo(ul);
                });
            };
        });
    } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use jquery selection on basis of class. 
Try 
$(".autocompleteclassname").autocomplete({

instead of

$("[id*=txtPort]").autocomplete({

I think txtbox id for 2nd row is not able to satisfy the jquery selector criteria.

Comment: It is unable to get the autocomplete with class name.@Krishan Kr Gaurav

Comment: Can you try by writing your aurtocomplete script outside "function Port(sender, args) {"?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property '_renderMenu': object is null or undefined @Krishan